# Start shutdown after one hour of playing - Trigger problems

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I am playing a game which is very addicting. I would rather limit the amount of time spent on that game to one hour per day, therefore, I need my (Windows 10) pc to turn off after one hour. I am using Windows' built-in Task Scheduler. I set it up to execute "shutdown.exe -s" one hour after executing "Steam Client Service". It does not appear to trigger anything.
Any thoughts on how to fix this so I can enjoy playing that game but still find a way to come back to my senses?

Thanks in advance,
Emanuele

Comment: It might help to see your full task scheduler task to see if there's anything that jumps out. I can't remember if it matters, but try doing a forward slash instead of a dash, e.g.: /s /f /t 60

Comment: What about a batch file to start the game, then call timeout.exe for 1hr before running shutdown.exe?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do it via Task Scheduler?